# Explanation of terminology in equation used for energy calculation using Hartree–Fock method

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I found in the literature that the energy of the Hartree–Fock method is given by the following equation:

$$E_\mathrm{HF} = \int (\Psi^* \hat{H}\Psi)\,\mathrm d\tau$$

The term $\Psi$ is the wave function, but what would the term $\Psi^*$ be?

Does anyone have a simple of explanation of what this may be?

Comment: Something with an asterisk in QC usually refers to a complex conjugate. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function#Definition) and a [related question on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/19259/what-does-psi-mean-in-schrodingers-formulation-of-quantum-mechanics).

Comment: I had seen it on wikipedia but thought there would be another explanation for that (physical meaning or something like that). Thanks for the references @andselisk

Comment: I highly recommend that you review the basic math of quantum mechanical operators before tackling the HF method. It will make a lot more sense that way.

Comment: @Andrew would you have review articles in the area to kindly recommend reading?

Comment: Levine's *Quantum Chemistry* textbook has a great section just on the math that only assumes familiarity with standard calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $x$ and $t,$ $\Psi(x,t)$ is a complex number. $\Psi^*$ is the conjugate of that number, no more, no less. The reason it seems like sometimes it's only the $t$ part that gets conjugated is simply that often it is the only part of the wavefunction that is complex. Let's use an example:

$$\Psi = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)\mathrm e^{-\mathrm iE_n t}.$$

We want to calculate $\Psi^*$. Well, since the conjugate of the product of two numbers is the product of their conjugates (that is, $(zw)^* = z^* w^*),$ let's do it step by step.

First we need to conjugate $\displaystyle\sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}$, but since it's a real number, it is equal to its conjugate. So we leave it alone and move on. Now we need to conjugate $\displaystyle\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right),$ but again, this is a real number, because $\sin x$ is real whenever $x$ is real. The last part is $\mathrm e^{-\mathrm iE_n t}$. This is actually complex, so we need to conjugate it, and its conjugate is $\mathrm e^{\mathrm iE_n t}.$ So putting it all together, we have

$$\Psi^* = \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{a}\right)\mathrm e^{\mathrm iE_n t}.$$